# Top questions/answers

Tags: discussion, api, tags, statistics

Is there a way to get a list of X questions/answers with the highest votes up, visits, etc?

Say I want to get the list of most voted questions in .NET category (tag) or Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`/questions?sort=votes`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions)

and

[`/questions/tagged/{tags}?sort=votes`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/tagged/java?help)

Comment: Yeah, just figured that out :) Thanks!
How about answers? Or you think it won't make sens to have the same thing for answers since they are related to questions.

Comment: @Heavy - answers can only be queried with respect to questions and users, not globally.